# Is there a season 2 in Kamisama Hajimemashita?

Tags: kamisama-kiss

I have finished this anime a time ago, but the last episode ended with a cliffhanger and I'm still wondering what is going to happen.

Answer (score 3):

According to Anime News Network, Kamisama Hajimemashita [gets second anime season](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2014-08-01/kamisama-kiss-kamisama-hajimemashita-manga-gets-2nd-anime-season/.77194), and it is currently airing this season (Winter 2014/2015) in Japan.

For further confirmation, the [manga entry of Kamisama Hajimemashita](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/manga.php?id=10642) shows [Kamisama Hajimemashita (TV2)](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=16255) being the sequel of [Kamisama Kiss (TV)](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=14441)<sup>1</sup> (which happens to be the second result [of the search](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/search?q=Kamisama%20Hajimemashita)).

<sup><sup>1</sup> *Kamisama Kiss* is the official localized English title of *Kamisama Hajimemashita*</sup>

Comment: @nhahtdh thanks for that, it actually reads a lot better now